# Python script throws an error and quits, OSError: [Errno 113] Connect call failed on portscan with Asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Found an interesting piece of code, on [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/emillynge/1eee20e8429caece09774af7e5614d69).

It works great, if the remote network is responding fast enough, with the default "timeout=0.1". however, in real live application, this often needs to be raised. Particularly, when scanning the network range, this script shoots out the error, with timeout as low as 0.2, almost each time.

Looking at the code, seems that the script is supposed to ignore such errors, but it, actually, instantly quits working.

```
     except (asyncio.TimeoutError, ConnectionRefusedError):
                pass
            else:
                yield task  # yield successful tasks
```

Here's the full error I get:

```
unhandled exception during asyncio.run() shutdown
task: <Task finished coro=<<async_generator_athrow without __name__>()> exception=RuntimeError("can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "port.py", line 130, in main
    async for task in streamer:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiostream/stream/advanced.py", line 43, in base_combine
    result = getter()
  File "port.py", line 79, in task_worker
    await asyncio.wait_for(conn, task.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 416, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/streams.py", line 77, in open_connection
    lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 959, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 946, in create_connection
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 464, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 494, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
OSError: [Errno 113] Connect call failed ('184.183.182.181', 8001)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "port.py", line 153, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main(sys.argv[1], ''.join(sys.argv[2:])))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "port.py", line 130, in main
    async for task in streamer:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiostream/stream/advanced.py", line 43, in base_combine
    result = getter()
  File "port.py", line 79, in task_worker
    await asyncio.wait_for(conn, task.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 416, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/streams.py", line 77, in open_connection
    lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 959, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 946, in create_connection
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 464, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 494, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
OSError: [Errno 113] Connect call failed ('184.183.182.181', 8001)
```

The goal is to ignore the error and to complete the loop.
Any input appreciated.

Comment: A possible problem with that piece of code is that it never **closes** the connections it opens. The process might exceed the maximum number of open files, thus affecting opening of subsequent connections in ways that were not envisioned by the script. Try rewriting the second part of `task_worker` [like this](https://pastebin.com/6dMQm5DV) and see if it helps.

Comment: The modified scripts gives a different error: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py:88: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'open_connection' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: Forgot to mention, initially, I have added the following to the sript, to cope with the open file limitation : import resource
soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (hard, hard))

Comment: Did you remove the original `conn = asyncio.open_connection(...)` line?

Comment: Tried both, with the line removed, it shoots out the similar errors, as per the original script: Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<open_connection() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/streams.py:53> exception=ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Connect call failed ('184.183.182.181', 8001)")> ......raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
OSError: [Errno 113] Connect call failed ('184.183.182.181', 8001)...During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:....RuntimeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine

Comment: Hmm. Try changing `except (asyncio.TimeoutError, ConnectionRefusedError)` to `except Exception` and see if that helps.

Comment: This finally worked, the script performs as it should now. Thank you very much.